# android -set adapter with data binding values varible programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

Do someone knows how can i set the values of adapter to a varible two way data binding?
I need something like this:

```
 MyCustomAdapter Adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(),
 R.layout.item, BR.values, image);
```

the values from the view model BaseObservable:

```
@Bindable
    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.values);
    }
```

how can I put BR.values there?
thx!

Comment: what is BR and what you get in BR.values?

Comment: Kindly put your MyCustomAdapter and Br model values.

Comment: BR is the view model of type  BaseObservable                                                                        @Bindable
        public List<String> getValues() {
            return values;
        }

            public void setValues(List<String> values) {
            this.values = values;
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.values);
        }

Comment: I don't think you should pass `BR` things like that. Instead, pass a `ObservableList<YourObservableObject>` to the adapter, set the variable in your itemviews xml and enable two way binding by doing somthing like: `android:text="@={myObsObject.name}"`

Comment: Dharmbir- i didn't understand your answare,    and @Amylinn , the problem is that i can't set the addapter items from the xml , I want to do it programmatically 'BR'

Comment: @Amylinn I meant paste your MyCustomAdapter and Br model values here :)

Comment: Please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414021/how-to-use-two-way-data-binding-in-android-for-dynamically-created-fields) and the answer from George Mount.

Comment: posts from George Mount -worth looking at! hope it would help me , thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is that you can't do binding programmatic at all by now, only from the XML.